# Tracking number of print() executions in a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

I'm working on this simple python program:

```
def func(x, printed):
  i = 0
  print(x)
  printed += 1
  while i < x:
    i = i+1
    func(x-1, printed)
  return printed

def main():
  x = int(input("Enter a positive number"))
  printed = 0
  result = func(x, printed)
  print("Printed", result)

main()
```

As you can see, I'm trying to find the number of times line 3 is executed but I'm always getting "Printed 1" because the recursion keeps restarting the function call. I thought I accounted for this but obviously I'm missing something.

What other approaches can I take to track the total number of times print(x) is executed?

For example, the input 2 should output:

2

1

0

1

0

Printed 5

And the input 3 should output:

3

2

1

0

1

0

2

1

0

1

0

2

1

0

1

0

Printed 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the line `func(x-1, printed)` just throws away its result. Although it increments `printed`, this only happens locally, inside the function, and only its return value communicates the result to the rest of the program.

To fix it, just update the function's current record by replacing its own count: `printed = function(x-1, printed)`.

(The alternative would be to keep a global variable `printed`, outside of all functions, and have all your functions update this with the `global` keyword. This would be easier, but well done on avoiding it - globals are evil and will cause more trouble than they're worth in any reasonably complex program.)

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(x, printed):
  i = 0
  print(x)
  printed += 1
  while i < x:
    i = i+1
    func(x-1, printed)
  return printed
```

You're recursively calling `func()` inside itself but you aren't capturing the return value.